# Method Chaining with Variables changing chain in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, methods, chaining

So hypothetically, let's say there's a few variables.

```
let itemMinify = true;
let itemResize = true;
```

And let's say that we've got a method chain that's processing an input.

```
something.minify().resize()....etc
```

Is there a way state whether a method should be included in the chain depending on a variable? I.e., if `itemMinify` was false, you'd see something like....

```
something.resize()....etc
```

I know that technically speaking you could just slap a ton of if statements or switch statements to get it to work, but I feel like there's got to be something that's more concise.

Comment: Not much that’s going to be more readable than breaking the chain, i.e. `if (itemMinify) something.minify(); if (itemResize) something.resize(); …`. `something = something.minify();` if each call actually produces a new object.

Comment: @Ry- `if (itemMinify) something = something.minify();`

Comment: @zerkms: A lot of chaining things just return the same object, because they’re bad.

Answer (score 0):

`['minify', 'resize'].forEach(action => {something[action]()}` should do the trick. You can generate the `['minify', 'resize']` array the way you want

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of ways to approach this but i'd seriously consider the pattern here. Whatever you are trying to do - it should be clear in your code.

There's nothing wrong with method chaining but it feels like you are trying to force something.

It seems your variables are related. I'd group these perhaps into an item config object.

```
const itemConfig = {
    minify: true,
    resize: false,
    ...so on
};
```

Then you could add some methods to iterate over the config object and perform conditional operations with the same keys. Because these objects have a dependency you could combine them into another object. (which should be easy for you to figure out)

```
const items = {
    minify: function() {
        // do some stuff here
    },
    ...so on
};

const itemConfigKeys = Object.keys(itemConfig);

itemConfigKeys.map(function(itemKey) {
    if (itemConfig[itemKey]) {
        const itemMethod = items[itemKey];
        itemMethod();
    }
});
```

I'm purposefully trying to be a bit vague here. There are a lot of things to consider as to how you approach a solution. This is one of many.